# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todos los datos relacionados a mi foreing key, con django?

Tags: python, django

¿Cómo puedo obtener los datos relacionados de mi foreignkey y al llenar mi formulario?

Tengo mi modelo:

```
class Service(models.Model): branch = models.ForeignKey(Endpoint, verbose_name="Sucursal", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

pr = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="prueba")
```

Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar la relación que trae "branch", me llene en el otro campo (en este caso "pr") los otros datos que trae esa relación de "branch".